# How to convert a UTF8 character to it's corresponding hex value

Tags: utf-8, elixir

I have to convert a utf8 character to its corresponding hex value in Elixir-Lang.

For example, if I pass "A" into the function, 41 is returned (which is the hex value for "A").

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for `Base.encode16/1`:

```
iex> Base.encode16 "A"
"41"
```